# Design this class keeping ORM in mind

Tags: java, oop, orm

I have an object consisting of 6 attributes, in which 5 of them uniquely defines (not derive) the 6th one:

```
public Class MyClass {

       private FirstAttribute first;

       private SecondAttribute second;

       private ThirdAttribute third;

       private FourthAttributeEnum fourth;

       private FifthAttributeEnum fifth;

       private SixthAttribute uniquelyDefined;  

}
```

I need to store the objects of this class in relational database. For all the unique combinations of first 5 attributes, the value of sixth changes (It might be same co-incidentally for different combinations but no relation is there, so sixth can't be the primary key).

As a primary key, I have defined another String which combines String representation of first 5 attributes.

I am looking for better implementations of this case. What would be the best way to restructure this class?

Comment: how can the combination of the first 5 attributes be your primary key ? can't you have something like {1,2,3,4,5 - 1} and {1,2,3,4,5 - 2} ?

Comment: @Pras No that can't happen in my case. Each object will have different combination of the first five attributes.

Comment: ok, first i like the idea of "technical PK" .. i won't mix the business attributes to generate a primary key but definitely a new column (String or Long or whatever keeping in mind that ORM mapping librairies such as Hibernate generate automatically PK for you) ... then, you will simply add a unique constraint on those first 5 attributes

Answer (score 0):

> As a primary key, I have defined another String which combines String
>   representation of first 5 attributes.

This might be one of the rare cases where surrogate primary key is preferred over a natural one. "Megabytes-long" primary keys are not a good idea since they are usually used all over the application (other tables, entity memory representations etc). You will also slow down lookup operations since your indexes will grow. Table reading might slow up also because rows will be too big.